# Docusign Success API redirect

Tags: docusignapi

after document signed response redirect URL, i need to redirect it based on multiple conditions.

Let say,

1. Payment Not completed -- Docusign success API redirect /api/signed/payment-not-paid
2. Payment completed -- Docusign success API redirect /api/signed/payment-completed

Docusign Node js API integration

Comment: 4th result in Google for "docusign redirect" https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sending-signers-to-different-url-if-they-decline-to-sign

Answer (score 0):

You can make the payment option required and as already suggested by Mike, follow the blog post steps.